# jython htmlunit error Cannot call method "then" of undefined

Tags: web-scraping, jython, htmlunit

The python code throws out an exception at `page = webclient.getPage("https://www.gartner.com/en/newsroom")`.

I modified the gartner.py script from http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/ only to quickly adjust the jython code to the current website version (see the xpath that works when tested in Selenium):

```
from com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit import WebClient as WebClient
from com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit import BrowserVersion as BrowserVersion

def main():
   webclient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED) # creating a new webclient object.

   page = webclient.getPage("https://www.gartner.com/en/newsroom") # getting the url
   articles = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='row newsletter']//a") # getting all the hyperlinks

   for article in articles:
      print ("Clicking on:", article)
      subpage = article.click() # click on the article link
      title = subpage.getByXPath("//div[@class='globalsite cmp-globalsite-columncontrol aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12']//*[@class='grid-norm  mg-t0']") # get title
      summary = subpage.getByXPath("//div[@class='globalsite cmp-globalsite-columncontrol aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12']//*[@class='grid-norm  subtitle mg-t15 mg-b15']") # get summary

      print(title)
      print(summary)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\xyz>jython C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\gartner2.py
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl WARNING Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.

...some CSS errors...

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener SEVERE Error during JavaScript execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\gartner2.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\gartner2.py", line 17, in main
    page = webclient.getPage("https://www.gartner.com/en/newsroom") # getting the url
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "then" of undefined (https://www.gartner.com/en/ruxitagentjs_ICA2SVfqru_10137171222133618.js#163)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:891)
     ....
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "then" of undefined (https://www.gartner.com/en/ruxitagentjs_ICA2SVfqru_10137171222133618.js#163)
```

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are actually asking. Are you requesting framework advice or do you want help with the exception?  Maybe you should rather ask two questions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm solely trying to tackle the exception so I'd appreciate any help on that. The reason I stressed I don't want to get deep into java is that I was hoping for a reply that would be considerate about my lack of knowledge of java

Comment: I noted when editing that you call the code differently from the linked example, lacking the argument -J-classpath "htmlunit-2.8/lib/*, but I guess that is not the problem. Actually you probably could remove all the code except for the one line. I would consider starting here: https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html and reporting bugs to their mailinglist.